# Slice string after period and before next space

Tags: python, string, slice

I am looping through SQL statements (strings) that look like this...

```
'SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3 from SCHEMA_1.TABLE_ABC MINUS SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3 from SCHEMA_2.TABLE_WXYZ..'
```

Each time I loop through, I want to capture the **first** table name and store it.  So anything after the first period (.) and before the next space.  Desired output from above example:

```
TABLE_ABC
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use `re.findall` here:

```
inp = 'SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3 from SCHEMA_1.TABLE_ABC MINUS SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3 from SCHEMA_2.TABLE_WXYZ..'
table_name = re.findall(r'\bfrom\s+[^.]+\.(\S+)', inp, flags=re.IGNORECASE)[0]
print(table_name)
```

This prints:

```
TABLE_ABC
```

Comment: or `re.search(r'from\s+[^.]+\.(\S+)', query, re.I).group(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in pure Python without importing any modules:

```
query = 'SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3 from SCHEMA_1.TABLE_ABC MINUS SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3 from SCHEMA_2.TABLE_WXYZ..'    
print(query.split('.', 1)[1].split(' ', 1)[0])
# TABLE_ABC
```

Comment: Thank you both.  Both worked perfectly for my needs. I don't think there will be any columns with dots in the name, but that's a good catch/consideration